# Questions about shift-invariant measures in ${\bf N}$

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

Let $P$ be a shift invariant diffused probability  measure defined on powerset of all natural numbers  ${\bf N}$(see,  van Douwen, Eric K. (1992). Finitely additive measures on ${\bf N}$. Topology Appl.${\bf 47(3)}$ 223--268.
[MR1192311](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1192311), DOI: [10.1016/0166-8641(92)90032-U](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(92)90032-U)). Let $\mu_1=\mu_2=P$.

${\bf Question 1.}$ Is Fubini theorem valid for the product measure $\mu_1\times \mu_2$?

Comment: Can you explain how product measure $\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$ is defined for finitely additive measures?

Comment: Let consider a family $\cal{F}$ of subset of $N \times N$ which can be presented as a finite union of disjoint sets of the form $A_i \times B_i(1 \le i \le n)$ as follows : $\mu_1\times \mu_2(\cup_{i=1}^n(A_i \times B_i))=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_1(A_i)\times \mu_2(B_i)$. $\cal{F}$ is an algebra. Now can be used Hahn-Banach theorem about extension of positive linear functionals.

Answer (score 0):

This example is due to D. Let consider a function $f(k,n): N^2 \to R$ defined by $f(k,n)=1$ for $k \le n$ and $f(k,n)=0$, otherwise. Then $\int_N(\int_Nf(k,n)dP(k))dP(n)=0$ and   $\int_N(\int_Nf(k,n)dP(n))dP(k)=1$.